# Generic bounded argument is incompatible with itself

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a generic method that accepts two typed arguments, one of them bounded by *itself*,

```
class Foo
{
    <T extends Foo, V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<T, V> destination)
    {
        if (value.isPresent())
        {
            destination.accept(~~this~~, value.get());
        }
    }
}
```

but compiler blames on the `this` argument, because

```
error: incompatible types: Foo cannot be converted to T
            destination.accept(this, value.get());
                               ^
  where T,V are type-variables:
    T extends Foo declared in method <T,V>myself(Optional<V>,BiConsumer<T,V>)
    V extends Object declared in method <T,V>myself(Optional<V>,BiConsumer<T,V>)
```

If `T` is a subtype of `Foo`, is clear that `Foo` is not for sure an instance of `T`.
But `this` being an extended of `Foo`, still is `Foo`.

Forcing the `(T) this` cast seems to ""work"".

**Update**

I want to use it the following way,

```
class Bar extends Foo
{
    void setAnswer(Integer toLife)
    {
    }
}

----

void outThere(Bar bar)
{
    bar.myself(Optional.of(42), Bar::setAnswer);
}
```

The proposal of wildcarded argument

```
class Foo
{
    <V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<? super Foo, V> destination)
    {
        if (value.isPresent())
        {
            destination.accept(this, value.get());
        }
    }
}
```

fails on the usage with,

```
error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
        bar.myself(Optional.of(42), Bar::setAnswer);
                                    ^
    method setAnswer in class Bar cannot be applied to given types
      required: Integer
      found: Foo,V
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Object declared in method <V>myself(Optional<V>,BiConsumer<? super Foo,V>)
```

Comment: Suppose Bar extends Foo. If there's a consumer that specifically wants a Bar (because a valid argument is *any* T which extends Foo), you can't just pass it a Foo. It won't work. It might rely on a method of Bar which Foo doesn't have. Change your BiConsumer to `BiConsumer<Foo,...` if that's what you meant.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you need the first generic type parameter at all.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to involve "self-ness" in the first place: `bar.myself(Optional.of(42), bar::setAnswer);` would work if you used a `Consumer<V>` instead. Plus, of course, `anOptional.ifPresent(bar::setAnswer)` would work, and not duplicate the `bar`.

Comment: "If `T` is a subtype of `Foo`, I don't understand why `this` (which is a `Foo` for sure) cannot be a `T`." `T` being a subtype of `Foo` does not imply that `Foo` is a subtype of `T`.

Comment: @newacct you are completelly right, I will re-formulate that question.

Answer (score 5):

> `T extends Foo`

It's *bounded* by `Foo`, but it isn't necessarily *actually* `Foo`. It could be any subtype of `Foo` instead.

Instead of defining a type variable, use a wildcard:

```
final BiConsumer<? super Foo, V> destination
```

---

Also, a better way to write the method body is:

```
value.ifPresent(consumer);
```

(There isn't really much advantage in invoking your method over just doing this directly).

---

Update for your update:

If you want to express something resembling a self type, you need to add another type variable to the class:

```
class Foo<F extends Foo<F>>
{
    <V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<? super F, V> destination) {
        if (value.isPresent())
        {
            // (F) is an unchecked cast, but is necessary, because
            // nothing constrains F to actually be "itself".
            destination.accept((F) this, value.get());
        }
    }
```

Then the `Bar` class is defined as:

```
class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
   void setAnswer(Integer toLife) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Then the `outThere` method works fine:

```
void outThere(Bar bar)
{
    bar.myself(Optional.of(42), Bar::setAnswer);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ohBJiM)

Comment: Sorry but I can't see why still any **subtype** of `Foo` **is not `Foo`**. Maybe my old-learned polimorphism lessons are lost.

Comment: @lucasvc: It is, but that isn't necessarily helpful - because your consumer accepts a `T`, not a `Foo`. Consider a `BiConsumer<String, String>` - you can't call `consumer.accept(new Object(), new Object())` on that, even though `String` extends `Object`. That's what you've effectively got here, where `T` is equivalent to `String` in this example and `Foo` is equivalent to `Object`.

Comment: @lucasvc Suppose the BiConsumer provided was `(Bar bar, Integer val) -> bar.thisMethodExistsOnBarButNotFoo(val)`. Foo can't satisfy that, it doesn't have that method.  All Bars are Foos but **not everything** which accepts a Bar can accept a Foo.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, but my idea **is the other way arround** of your example, `BiConsumer<Object, Object>` with callign `consumer.accept(new String(), new String())`: I try to declare a *parent* but calling to it with any *child*.

Comment: @lucasvc: That's not what your code says though. You've got `T extends Foo`, and you're calling the code from within `Foo`. So it's fine for `T` to be `FooSubclass`, so you'd be passing the *parent* type (`Foo`, the type of `this`) to something that's specific to the *child* (the parameter type of the `BiConsumer<T, V>`). If you had `T super Foo` it would be okay (for that argument).

Comment: The `F extends Foo<F>` bound is not utilized; your code compiles equally with `class Foo<F>`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, `Foo` has two subclasses, `Foo1` and `Foo2`, both not overriding the `myself()` method. Then:

```
Foo1 me = ...;
Optional<String> value = ...
BiConsumer<Foo2,String> consumer = ...;
me.myself(value, consumer);
```

matches

```
<T extends Foo, V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<T, V> destination) {...}
```

with `V` being `String` and `T` being `Foo2`, while `this` is of class `Foo1`, so you can't pass it into a `Foo2` consumer.

And that's what the compiler detected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no guarantee that your `T` is compatible with `this`.

It could that the `BiConsumer` is referring to a something that `extends T`, then `T` would not fit in. The issue is that you are inferring `T` and that might not be compatible with `this`.

If you really want this, then you should remove `T` all together and just use `Foo`.

If you want anything that extends `Foo` and wishes to infer that, then you could use `super` instead.

```
<V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<? super Foo, V> destination) {
    if ( value.isPresent() ) {
        destination.accept(this, value.get());
    }
}
```

You are going to find some issues with this approach though.

Otherwise, you could also use **Foo directly** as mentioned:

```
public static class Foo { 
    <T, V> void myself(final Optional<V> value, final BiConsumer<Foo, V> destination) {
        if ( value.isPresent() ) {
            destination.accept(this, value.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you are really sure you could **cast** it, but that is not really recommended.